# Extremely slow updating of contextMenus items

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am building a Chrome extension that creates a context menu list on extension load. Once the user right clicking on an element, the selector of it needs to be passed on to extension JavaScript from content script.
Problem starts when a right click occurs and content script sends a message to extension JavaScript to update all the contextmenu items with selector of element. Since the update method of Chrome extension contextmenu is anyc, user sees no element sector with contextmenu items and they start to appear only after right clicking 5-6 times.

I am struggling to find a way do it quickly but since the chrome.contextMenus.update API is async and needs to be called for each item, it takes ages to complete. Can there be some other wayout so that items of context menu are dynamically created or updated as per the element clicked on the first right click itself means no wait time at all?

Here is overview of my code:

extension js:

```js
//Start Code for extension js
function GetAllAvailableCMCommands() {
  //Format - [{"Command":__command,"AvailableContext":[__context],"CMItemType":__itemtype}]
  var _c = "Command",
    _a = "AvailableContext",
    _ct = "CMItemType";

  return [
    {[_c]: "item1", [_a]: ["link"],[_ct]: null},
    {[_c]: "item2", [_a]: ["link"],[_ct]: null},
    {[_c]: "item3", [_a]: ["link"],[_ct]: null},
  ];
}

function CreateCM(type, id, title, contexts) {
  chrome.contextMenus.create({
    "type": !type ? "normal" : type,
    "id": id,
    "title": title,
    "contexts": contexts
  });
}

function UpdateCMItemTitle(id, newTitle) {
  chrome.contextMenus.update(id, {
    "title": newTitle
  });
}

function UpdateCMItemsOnEleClkd(request, sendResponse) {
  if (request.clickedEle && request.selector) {
    var cm = GetAllAvailableCMCommands();
    for (var i = 0; i < cm.length; i++) {
      var json = cm[i];
      if (Object.keys(json).length) {
        var ac = json.AvailableContext;
        if (ac.length) {
          UpdateCMItemTitle(json.Command, json.Command + " " + request.selector);
        }
      }
    }
    sendResponse({
      issuccess: true
    });
  }
}

var cm = GetAllAvailableCMCommands();
for (var j = 0; j < cm.length; j++) {
  var json = cm[j];
  if (Object.keys(json).length) {
    var ac = json.AvailableContext;
    if (ac.length) {
      CreateCM(json.CMItemType, json.Command, json.Command, json.AvailableContext);
    }
  }
}

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
  if (request.func) {
    switch (request.func) {
      case "UpdateCMItems":
        UpdateCMItemsOnEleClkd(request, sendResponse);
        break;
    }
  }
});

//End Code for extension js
```

content script:

```js
//Start Code for content script

document.addEventListener("mousedown", function(e) {
  target = e.target;
  selector = e.id; //assuming elements have an id attribute
  var msg = {
    "func": "UpdateCMItems",
    "selector": selector,
  };
  chrome.runtime.sendMessage(msg, function(res) {
    if (res.issuccess) {
      console.log("context menu items for the current elements are updated");
    }
  });
}, false);

//End Code for content script
```

The intention is to see context menu items are updated with ID of current element. For example if an input box with id=txtLogin is right clicked, context-menu should show

```
item1 id=txtLogin
item2 id=txtLogin
item3 id=txtLogin
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment but please check my code once if possible. I am doing the same thing already. I believe you didn't read the entire content, I've done almost everything and the issue is time lag not the creation or updation.

Comment: Oh, my browser was not showing the scroll bars

Comment: Well, you can use mouseover event...

Comment: @wOxxOm yes have tried that too, doesn't help. those chrome api update takes a lot to update all items. problem is it work in 1 by 1 pattern for each item so several async api calls. there is nothing there to update all items or group of items at once.

Comment: Then there's nothing you can do except reducing the menu to just one item.  When it's clicked, you can show a menu in the page asking what to do next, for example.

Comment: @Makyen no, the person there was trying to make change in context menu using content script itself instead of sending message to the extension and the answer tells how to do that correctly. my question is related to the speed/performance of updates, it does what it needs but its too late.

Comment: @wOxxOm that's not an option. if you've ever use selenium IDE, you will notice it changes all its menu items per the item right clicked and there is no lag at all. i am trying to do that way.

Comment: If you want us to think that this is different, then provide a *complete*, but minimal, [mcve] that actually duplicates the problem. That means enough code that we can copy it into files and see the same problem. It almost always, for a Chrome extension, will require a *manifest.json*. Given your code has at least one syntax error, it's clearly not what you're actually using.

Comment: The reason that a [mcve] is required is that *we want to help*. It is **much** easier to help if we don't have to recreate any of the code needed to duplicate the problem. This is code that you already have. So, please help us to help you and provide a *complete* [mcve] that duplicates the problem. Without a [mcve], the amount of effort required to even begin to help you is **much** higher, which *significantly* reduces the number of people willing/able to help you. Even if we put out the extra effort, we have to **guess** at significant portions of what your problem might be.

Comment: @p_champ, selenium uses remote debugger protocol so it's different.

Comment: i was about to provide the entire code but just noticed question has been closed and marked as duplicate to an answer which doesn't match to this at all. really sad to learn legitimate and non duplicate questions can also be closed forcibly. I'll better do my own research now. Thanks everyone for concerns here.